# Honeycomb Document Parse Error

Tags: android, parsing, android-3.0-honeycomb

I've searched far and wide about this issue, tried many fixes but I cannot get any to work..

I'm trying to parse an xml file from my server, I can retrieve the file okay but when I go to parse it, it errors. Here is my code:

```
    public final static Document parse(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            // ERRORS HERE
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            //
        doc = db.parse(is);  
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }     
    return doc;
}
```

and here is the error I'm getting:

```
12-02 20:26:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(11600): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-02 20:26:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:48)
12-02 20:26:22.340: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at com.arayray.bootanimationutility.tablet.functions.DownloadFunctions.parse(DownloadFunctions.java:41)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And you are sure xml is not null?

That appears to be what the error is saying.

Comment: I fixed it... It seemed to be strictmode blocking my function